# Is there a shortcut for calculating $\sum_{d\mid 2000} \tau(d)\cdot \sigma(d)\cdot \phi(d)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I know how to calculate that, but the procedure is too long and boring. Is there any theorem that can be used to solve that exercise, to simplify the solution?

Comment: It's a multiplicative function.

Comment: Everything is multiplicative so from $\phi(p^k)$ and $\sigma(p^k)$ you know $\sigma \star \phi(p^k) = \sum_{m=0}^k \sigma(p^m) \phi(p^{k-m})$ and so on. Also note all the Dirichlet series generating functions are expressed in term of $\zeta(s),\zeta(s-1)$

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! The functions $\sigma(d)$ and $\phi(d)$ are well-known but you should mention what the function $\tau(n)$ means

Comment: @Peter In this context, $\tau(n)$ is also well-known as the number of divisors function.  Cheers!